# New deployment slot for azure websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a REST API call to create a **new deployment slot** in Azure website?

[image]

I am not able to find anything [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166981.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Azure PowerShell cmdlets.  For example, I tested this with a site named "cloudallocweb" in East US and then used the following command to create a new deployment slot in the cloudallocweb site.

```
New-AzureWebsite -Name "cloudallocweb" -Location "East US" -Slot "test"
```

Peeking into what the New-AzureWebsite cmdlet is doing in the command above, I found this POST operation which is basically the [Create a web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166986.aspx) REST API.  Notice that it is passing the WebSpace setting (matching in the URL), which I don't see documented in the REST API.

[image]

At any rate, it appears the [Create a Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166986.aspx) REST API is what you need.  This makes sense considering that a deployment slot is really just a web site.  You may also take a look at the [List Webspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166961.aspx) API to find the right web space value for your site.

Following the steps above, the new deployment slot will appear under the original site as shown here. You can then swap the deployment slots using the portal, REST API, or the Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot cmdlet.

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that , I will not be able to swap 2 websites if the 2nd website is not in the same deployment slot as the 1st website. What should I take care while creating the 2nd website then?

Comment: The steps I gave you will enable you to swap them.  Did you try it?